# Using wmic to get drives space information in human readable format

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, diskspace

I want server drive space information in readable format in GB using wmic, i am using below code
can anyone have idea how to get it in gb.

```
wmic logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption
```

output i am getting is:

```
Caption       FreeSpace          Size
C:           19681808384        64078475264
Z:           801183551488      1000240963584
```

Comment: Powershell will be a better option `gwmi win32_logicaldisk | Format-Table DeviceId, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}`

Comment: The problem you are going to run into is that batch files can only do math on 32bit integers.  So you need a different scripting language to do the math.

Comment: can you provide addition of column in above command that how much % memory is left free on respective drive?